# Apache config: Permissions, Directories and Locations

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, permissions, configuration

I'm trying to get my head around apache configuration to fix a problem I'm having but after a few hours I've decided to ask here.

This is what I've got at the moment:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/svn>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/hg>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location /hg>
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "Engage HG"
        AuthDigestProvider file
        AuthUserFile /opt/hg/hgweb.users
        Require valid-user
</Location>

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess hg processes=3 threads=15
WSGIProcessGroup hg
WSGIScriptAlias /hg "/opt/hg/hgweb.wsgi"

<Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /var/svn/repos

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion"
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/users
        require valid-user
</Location>
```

I'm trying to get my head around how it's all laid out and how directories relate to locations/etc

For /hg I get asked for a password but to /svn I get a 403 forbidden...

the error I get is:

[client 10.80.10.169] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/svn

When I remove the  entry it works fine..

I can't figure out how to get it linking to the /var/svn directory

Comment: missing AuthDigestProvider file in svn I think

Comment: Why do use different authentication types? hg=digest, svn=basic? And 403 can be caused by file/folder permissions - www-data needs access to /var/svn/repos

Comment: we had svn setup (all our servers commit their /etc/ directory to svn) and i added hg to it and didn't want to change the svn setup.

Answer (score 0):

Please check directory permissions:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/

You should use the same authentication mehtod:

- Location /hg uses digest auth
- Location /svn uses basic auth

And your configuration can rely on inheritance:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/svn>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/hg>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location /hg>
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "Engage HG"
        AuthDigestProvider file
        AuthUserFile /opt/hg/hgweb.users
        Require valid-user
</Location>

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess hg processes=3 threads=15
WSGIProcessGroup hg
WSGIScriptAlias /hg "/opt/hg/hgweb.wsgi"

<Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /var/svn/repos

        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "Subversion"
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/users
        require valid-user
</Location>
```

Ensure that the AuthUserFiles exist!

Comment: I've updated with the error I get - I can't get the /svn url to link to /var/svn it seems - if I delete the <Directory /> entry it works fine

Comment: Please use digest authentication - see my edited config...